# Military slang: colors instead of flag

Tags: military

Where does this come from? Why do soldiers talk about their color(s?) instead of their flag (like in capture the flag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not so much slang as an extended or metonymous use.  The sense development is fairly clear.  The OED has it like this:

> **1.** A hue or tint.
>
> **d.** A colour, or each of a combination of colours, which is distinctive or symbolic of an institution or group, as a school, political party, or street gang. *Cf. senses 14, 19a.*
>
> **14.** *Chiefly Brit., Austral., and N.Z.* Political allegiance. *Now chiefly in extended metaphors*.
>
> **19a.** *In pl.* An item or items of a particular colour worn to identify or distinguish an individual or a member of a group; spec. (originally) the cognizance or insignia of a knight; (later) a rosette, ribbon, etc., worn as the badge of a political party; (now chiefly) a jockey's silks; the kit worn by a member of a sports team.
>
> **20a.**  *In pl.* Usually referring collectively to the particular combination of flags flown by a given ship or carried by a regiment.
>
> **20b.** *In pl.* By metonymy: a regiment; (later also more generally) the armed forces of a country. In later use usually as retained in set expressions, as to desert one's colours, to join the colours, service with the colours, etc., where sense 20a   is often understood, without metonymy.
>
> **20d.** *Chiefly U.S. (orig. U.S. Navy). In pl.* A national flag, esp. as an object of allegiance.